# A Clarification on Computing the Riemann Invariant for the Shallow Water Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, hyperbolic-equations

The shallow water wave equation [is given by](https://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DN2255/ndiff10/DN2255L_2a_10.pdf):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
h \\
u 
\end{bmatrix} _t +
\begin{bmatrix}
u & h \\
g & u
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
h \\
u 
\end{bmatrix} _x
$$

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors [are](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eigensystem%20%5B%7B%7Bu%2Ch%7D%2C%7Bg%2Cu%7D%7D%5D): $\lambda_\pm = u \pm \sqrt{gh} \quad r_\pm =\begin{bmatrix}
h \\
\pm \sqrt{gh} 
\end{bmatrix}$

[This document](https://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DN2255/ndiff10/DN2255L_2a_10.pdf) outlines how to compute the Riemann invariant. In particular, using the components of the eigenvectors (say for the positive one) they write: $$0 = h \, du + \sqrt{gh} \, dh = h\left(du + \sqrt{\frac g h}\,dh\right) = h\,\,d(u + 2\sqrt{gh})$$

I follow the computation, but in the eigenvector, it looks like the first coefficient is associated with the $h$-coordinate (in this case $h$) and the second is associated with the $u$-coordinate (in this case $\sqrt{gh}$). However when they write the differential, they associate $h$ with $du$ and $\sqrt{gh}$ with $dh$. This confuses me, why is the differential switched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left eigenvectors are used, not the right ones. This is because you are looking for a function of $w=(h,u)$ that is constant on one of the curves where $\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda$. If $f$ is such a function then on that curve you have by the chain rule
$$0=\frac{df}{dt}= [f_h \, f_u](w_t+\lambda w_x)=[f_h \, f_u](-A+\lambda)w_x.$$
This holds if the gradient of $f$ is a left eigenvector.

---

First note that $(\sqrt{gh} \, h)$ is a left eigenvector of
$\begin{bmatrix}
u & h \\
g & u 
\end{bmatrix}$
so that we have:
\begin{align}
0 &= \left[\sqrt{gh} \quad h\right] \left(
-\begin{bmatrix}
u & h \\
g & u 
\end{bmatrix}
+ \lambda\right) \begin{bmatrix} h \\ u
\end{bmatrix}_x
\\
& \text{continuing...} \\
&= h\left[\sqrt{\frac g h} \quad 1\right] \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
h \\
u 
\end{bmatrix}_t
+ \lambda \begin{bmatrix} h \\ u
\end{bmatrix}_x \right)
\end{align}
Letting $f_h = \sqrt{\frac g h}, f_u = 1, \lambda = \frac{dx}{dt}$ we have:
\begin{align}
&= h\left[f_h \quad f_u\right] \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
h \\
u 
\end{bmatrix}_t
+ \frac{dx}{dt} \begin{bmatrix} h \\ u
\end{bmatrix}_x \right) \\
&= h \frac{df}{dt}
\end{align}
Where $f = u + 2\sqrt{gh}$ is constant along characteristics given by $\lambda$ ($h$ is non-zero in general).

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but am having trouble following in the context of the computation above. Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: They are using the left eigenvector $(\sqrt{gh},h)$. Also expressing the computation in terms of 1-forms instead of gradient is interesting.

Comment: $f_h = \partial_h (hu+2h\sqrt{gh}) \neq \sqrt{gh}$ though. How are these entries being computed?

Comment: The factor $h$ is the key.  $(\sqrt{gh},h)$ is not a gradient, but it is $h$ times a gradient. And any multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector. $h$ is called an integrating factor.

Comment: I edited your answer and added detail, is this correct? thanks!

Comment: Also in 2D systems, I guess its always possible to find an integrating factor. How does one go about this in general? It says in the linked notes, but I don't quite follow.